# Find the vectorial form of Ax=b with given particular solution

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm kind of confused about this problem. I have the given Row reduced echelon form of the matrix A and I'm given a particular solution set. The questions asks me to determine the vectorial form to the solution Ax = b.

Basically, i don't know the original matrix A and i dont know b. However i am given the RREF of A and a particular solution X.

Can someone tell me how do i proceed to resolve the problem?

Comment: What is the "vectorial form"?

Comment: you could say $x = A^{-1} b$

Comment: @parsiad i'm sorry i translated from French to English. I think it only means in vector form

Comment: @Doug M The inverse of A would return to the original matrix A?

Comment: $Ax = b\implies A^{-1} A x = A^{-1} b \implies x = A^{-1} b$

Comment: You don't need the original matrix A. Because, $Ax=B$ and $A^{'}x=B^{'}$ have the same solutions, where $A^{'}$ and $B^{'}$ are the matrices after applying elementary row operations. This is the reason for converting into RRE as you can read off the solution (x). For more help regarding why they have the same solution, refer: [these notes](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~ritumoni/Lecture%203%20and%204.pdf)